# RageMP Server convert to FiveM?

Tags: server, fivem, grand-theft-auto

I have a full RageMP Roleplay server and would like to port all the features and scripts to FiveM to make them work. Could someone help me or show me how to do this?

Maybe someone who could do it for me or could show me how i could do it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is off-topic. Please read about what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here and what questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).